# Build cache nodejs + vuejs and vite on google cloud engine

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, caching, vite

I have an issue very annoying for several days.
I have an issue with a cache of the navigator who verry strongly all users needs do "hard refresh" to show a version of the application.

The problematic is very annoying on mobile phone, that's impossible to do hard refresh.

Any files are refreshing in a navigator.

I work on a project VueJs 2.7 + Vite to the front end, nodejs + express to the backend.
The structure of folder is

```
/my-vue-app
├── /vue-src  
│   ├── main.js  
│   ├── App.vue  
|   |── vite.config.js
│   └── ...  
├── /public        #AFTER BUILD
│   ├── index.html # Fichier HTML principal
│   └── ...        # Autres ressources statiques
├── service.js     # Node.js avec Express
├── app.yaml       # Fichier de configuration pour le déploiement GCE
├── package.json   # Fichier de configuration des dépendances
```

In my node application I use a static folder public

```
const publicRoot = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(publicRoot));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '0');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
```

I add my config vite if we need :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue2";
import { loadEnv } from "vite";
import Components from "unplugin-vue-components/vite";
import { VuetifyResolver } from "unplugin-vue-components/resolvers";

const path = require("path");

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "");

  return {
    base: "/",
    build: {
      commonjsOptions: {
        esmExternals: true,
      },
      outDir: "../public",
      cssCodeSplit: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          entryFileNames: "[name]-[hash].js",
        },
      },
    },
    css: {
      order: {
        before: [/app.css$/],
        after: [/app_responsive.css$/],
      },
    },
    server: {
      host: env.VITE_URL,
      port: env.VITE_PORT,
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
        "@uielements": path.resolve(__dirname, "./uielements"),
        "@components": path.resolve(__dirname, "./components"),
      },
      extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"],
    },
    define: {
      "process.env": env,
    },
    plugins: [
      vue(),
      Components({
        resolvers: [VuetifyResolver()],
      }),
    ],
  };
});
```

And my app.yaml to send my project on server google engine :

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
handlers:
  - url: /public
    static_dir: public
    expiration: 0s
runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
#network:
#  session_affinity: true
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: $NODE_ENV
liveness_check:
  path: "/api/healthcheck"
  initial_delay_sec: 300
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 10
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
readiness_check:
  path: "/api/healthcheck"
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 10
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 300
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1.5
```

Thank you per advance to your help

Comment: I have update the version of Vue 2 to Vue 3 but any changement

I have desactivate cloudflare but any changement...

I need help please